# Laravel MercadoPago Invalid Argument Foreach

Tags: laravel, mercadopago

muy buenos días ! estoy intentando implementar el SDK de MercadoPago en Laravel 8 y estoy teniendo el siguiente problema:

intente de varias formas pero no hubo caso, así que me decante por hacer la clásica, enviar los datos desde el controller directamente para verificar que este funcionando y para mi sorpresa tampoco funciona...

estoy usando el dx-php original de mercadopago

```
public function pagar(Order $order): string
  {
     $preference = new Preference();
  
  # Building an item
  
  $item1 = new Item();
  $item1->id = "00001";
  $item1->title = "item"; 
  $item1->quantity = 1;
  $item1->unit_price = 100;
  
  $item2 = new Item();
  $item2->id = "00001";
  $item2->title = "item"; 
  $item2->quantity = 1;
  $item2->unit_price = 100;
  
  $preference->items = array($item1, $item2);
  
  $preference->payment_methods = array(
    "excluded_payment_types" => array(
      array("id" => "credit_card")
    ),
    "installments" => 12
  );
  
  $preference->external_reference = "A Custom External Reference";
  
  $preference->save();

      if (config('payment-methods.use_sandbox')) {
        return $preference->sandbox_init_point;
      }

      return $preference->sandbox_init_point;
  }
```

Todos los metodos que usé me tira el mismo error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

alguien me puede decir que es lo que está mal?
este es el codigo del foreach esta en la api oficial

```
public function proccess_causes($causes){

        if(isset($causes['code']) && isset($causes['description'])){

            $this->add_cause($causes['code'], $causes['description']);

        }else{

            foreach ($causes as $cause){

                if(is_array($cause) && (!isset($cause['code']) && !isset($cause['description']))){

                    $this->proccess_causes($cause);

                }else{

                    $this->add_cause($cause['code'], $cause['description']);

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Donde esta el `foreach`, no muestras esa parte del codigo. Revisastes que datos tiene tu variable para hacer la "iteracion"?

Comment: hola! muchas gracias por responder, ahi la agregué, esta en un archivo que viene con el sdk

Answer (score 2):

Resuelto, dejo por si alguien más tiene este problema!

Agregue el SDK::setAccesToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

el problema resultaba de que en la página de la documentación hay una variable con el nombre ClientSecret y en la versión nueva es AccessToken

```
{
     SDK::setAccessToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');


     $preference = new Preference();
  
  # Building an item
  
  $item = new Item();
  $item->id = "00001";
  $item->title = "item"; 
  $item->quantity = 1;
  $item->unit_price = 100;
  
  $preference->items = array($item);

  $preference->back_urls = array(
            "success" => "https://localhost/success",
            "failure" => "http://localhost/failure",
            "pending" => "http://localhost/pending"
        );
        $preference->auto_return = "approved";
  
  $preference->save();

      if (config('payment-methods.use_sandbox')) {
        return $preference->sandbox_init_point;
      }

      return $preference->sandbox_init_point;
  }
```